# How many basic operations are there in an algorithm for the simple multiplication of two numbers of equal length?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, arithmetic, multiplication

***BACKGROUND:***

**Note:** The following question arose in my mind when watching [this lecture](https://class.coursera.org/algo-004/lecture/165) (watch at 5:30 minutes if you will).

**Assumption:** Just for the sake of this question, let's assume that the term "basic operation" means an addition or a multiplication operation between two single-digit numbers.

**Now we have to calculate the number of basic operations involved in the simple multiplication (*the one we learnt in 3rd grade*) of any two numbers, provided that both the numbers have the same length (i.e. the number of digits).**

Let's say `n` represents the length of the numbers.

Let the numbers be `1234` and `5678`. The following image shows the multiplication:

[image]

As you can see, each row (i.e. each partial product of the first number with a digit of the second number) involves `4` multiplication operations, and `4` addition operations (think of the carries). *Depending on the number of carries (and thus depending on the original numbers), in the case of any two numbers, in each row, it could be at least `0` additions (no carry) and at most `4` additions (a carry from each digit-to-digit multiplication).*

**In other words, each row involves `≤ 2n` operations. As there are `n` rows, so the basic operations in all the rows are `n(2n)`, or 2n<sup>2</sup>.**

---

***QUESTION:***

Now comes that one final addition (shown in black pen in the image). From the video lecture

> The final addition requires a comparable number of operations.
>   Roughly, say, another at-most 2n<sup>2</sup> operations.

**The question is**

1. **What is meant by "comparable" number of operations?**
2. **Now, there will be at-most `n-1` `_`'s in the partial products, which means `n-1` addition operations. Apart from those, there will be *at-least* `n` additions (if there isn't a carry from the addition of the left-most digits in the partial products), and *at-most* `n+1` additions (if there IS a carry from the addition of the left-most digits in the partial products). This makes a total of, at-most, `n-1+n+1` or `2n` addition operations in this step. So why are they saying 2n<sup>2</sup>?**

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell what anyone means by "comparable" in a specific context. I would take it to mean "of the same order", so something like $n^2$, maybe $100\cdot n^2$ or $0.0001\cdot n^2$, but not $n$ or $n^3$.

The final addition is doing (roughly) $n$ additions of numbers of (roughly) non-$\_$ $n$ digits, and each of those additions takes (roughly) $n$ additions of single digit numbers. So that's why you end up with (roughly) $n^2$ additions.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. The answer for the first question has clarified my mind, but about the answer to the second question, I am confused about "non-_ n digits"? What do you mean by "non-_  n"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting each partial product then adding all of them at the end, let's keep a register that is `2n` digits long, initially full of zeros, and we will update it as we go.

After each `n + 1` digit-long partial product, we add it into the sum register.  We need to shift it one digit higher each round.  We need to do `n + 1` additions, then need to do more additions to cascade any carries.  So there will be upper limit of `2n` additions into the sum register each round.  Since there are `n` rounds, we get a total of `2n²` operations for the sum register round.

This is why it's comparable to the multiplication round, although the multiplication round is a mix of multiplication and addition while the sum register round is just additions.